# Microsoft Visual 2010 missing templates

Tags: visual-studio-2010

how can i download other templates to MS visual 2010 express?
i can make only visual c++ projects... i have installed 8.0 9.0 10.0 versions

in 9.0 folder i have some folders named VC, VC#, VB,sqlserver,XML,VSTA,SDK,MSDN Express Library

can i just copy it to my 10.0 directory?

i tried devene.exe /InstallVSTemplates but console writed something like this: devenv.exe is not recognized as an internal..... and yes,i had set the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\

im also missing directories C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates and
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates

Comment: Maybe just a typo here in your post but it's **devenv.exe**, not *devene.exe*.

Comment: yes, i know,but i find both devenv/devene that should help, i tried both but didnt work

Comment: The old Express editions only support a single language.  Clearly you have the C++ edition.  If you also want to write C# or VB.NET programs then you need the corresponding Express edition for those languages.  Or just use the current Express 2013 for Windows Desktop edition, it no longer is split by language.  A bigger download because of that, the ultimate reason these old Express editions were split.  It isn't very "express" if it take hours to download :)

Answer (score 1):

VS Express Edition SKUs usually only support a very limited set of project templates, forcing you to explicitly install distinct Express Edition SKUs (Web, Phone, etc.).

If your VS Express (for Desktop) is missing the C# and VB.Net project templates you should be able to restore them by running a repair install.